# How to view content security policy violation reports in rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, browser, rubygems, content-security-policy

I used secure_headers gem https://github.com/twitter/secureheaders and i configure the csp as

```
config.csp = {
:enforce => true,
:default_src => 'http://* inline',
:report_uri => "/report",
:connect_src => 'self',
:style_src => 'self inline',
:script_src => 'self inline eval',
:font_src => 'self'
}
```

but still i can't view the reports in my `http://localhost:3000/report` and page is not redirecting

Comment: Hi EMR, I wrote the gem. I'm a little confused about the question. /reports is just where the CSP reports from the browser are sent. You can change this value to anything you want, like a public logging server. The requests will show up in your logs. If you want a front end to view things, you might want to check out loggly or splunk storm.

Comment: # Where reports are sent. Use protocol relative URLs if you are posting to the same domain (TLD+1). Use paths if you are posting to the application serving the header
  :report_uri  => '//mysite.example.com',

Comment: If I pass a complete URL to the report_uri, I am still unable to view any violations. It says page not found (404) on my Rails app

Comment: Yes. No matter what you pass, you will get the same result. There is no page/controller/etc behind it. It is up to you to add the page. But as I said, most people will post reports to a logging endpoint.

Answer (score 4):

EDIT:

https://report-uri.io/ offers CSP reporting capabilities. They give you a report-uri, and they manage the incoming reports!

---

Currently the gem does not have any built-in support for aggregating/viewing the reports. This question got me thinking so I filed https://github.com/twitter/secureheaders/issues/71

Please add your thoughts. I don't think it is a trivial task to build something meaningful, but I'm beginning to see how valuable it could be. There's also a good amount of low hanging fruit that might be good enough for the time being.

Comment: i used this gem, how to retrieve request payload in ruby, i got empty string while get `request.raw_post`

Comment: https://github.com/twitter/secureheaders/blob/master/app/controllers/content_security_policy_controller.rb uses params.to_json. Does that work for you?

Comment: In controller `request.body.inspect` gives #<StringIO:0x00000007a1a6d8>, and can see the params['csp-report'] on rails console only using firefox and chromium and not in google chrome

Comment: no, i am not getting any POST parameters `params.to_json` returns only the GET params and my Rails version is 3.2.15

Answer (score 2):

The Secure Headers Gem does not provide a reporting endpoint for CSP violations. It is something you would have to build yourself or use a solution that provides both out of the box.

I posted an overview of the different ways of deploying a Content Security Policy with Ruby on Rails, including SecureHeaders Gem and Templarbit (which includes a reporting endpoint): https://www.templarbit.com/blog/2018/03/14/content-security-policy-with-ruby-on-rails